# Copying text from one field to other using 'id' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have to copy the shipping name and zip in the billing name and zip if the checkbox is checked and keep billing name and zip empty if checkbox is unchecked.

Following is my JavaScript code:

```
function billingFunction(){
  if(document.getElementById('same').checked==true){
    document.getElementById("billingName").value = document.getElementById("shippingName").value;
    document.getElementById("billingZip").value = document.getElementById("shippingZip").value;
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("billingZip").value = '';
    document.getElementById("billingName").value = '';
  }
}
```

`same` is the id of the checkbox.

What is wrong with this code? I can't use jQuery and I have to use the `id` attribute to access the HTML.

Comment: I don't see any issues with the code. Did you try debugging? Also, please post relevant HTML.

Comment: Without seeing the associated HTML, can only guess you haven't messed up the ID's and that all those elements are `input`'s - when you say "what is wrong with this code" ... what do you mean? what is happening? **how** and **when** are you calling this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript looks good, so that leaves me to assume the problem lies with how you are triggering the `billingFunction()` function.

I recommend doing something like so:

```
//use your same billingFunction
function billingFunction(){
    ...
}
/*
Once the document is ready, attach an event listener to the checkbox
which fires the function when the checkbox is changed
*/
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('same').addEventListener('change', billingFunction);
}
```

This wiats for the page to be reday before attaching an eventListener to your checkbox. When the checkboxes value is changed (checked/unchecked), it triggers the billingFunction.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Just call the billingFunction() on click of the checkbox.

```js
function billingFunction(){
  
  if(document.getElementById('same').checked==true){
    document.getElementById("billingName").value = document.getElementById("shippingName").value;
    document.getElementById("billingZip").value = document.getElementById("shippingZip").value;
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("billingZip").value = '';
    document.getElementById("billingName").value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
shippingName: <input type='text' id='shippingName' /><br />
shippingZip: <input type='text' id='shippingZip' /><br />
<br />
Copy Same? <input type="checkbox" id='same' onclick='billingFunction()'/>I have a car 
<br /><br />
billingName: <input type='text' id='billingName' /><br />
billingZip: <input type='text' id='billingZip' /><br />
```